# how to write a function to find prime numbers in a range in RStudio

Tags: arguments, range, rstudio, primes

I want to write a function to ask a user for a range and then return the prime numbers in that range.
But I dont know how to define inputs?

```
prime<-function(x,y){
  u<-range(x:y)
  for (u in range){
    for(j in 2:u-1){
      if (u%%j==0){
        print("u is prime")
      }
    }
  }
```

}`enter code here`
Help me to edit this code. Thank ypu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small numbers (less than 1 million), implement trial division by primes less than 1000:

```
primes_less_than_1000 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613,
617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

def is_prime(n):
    factor = 0
    if n in primes_less_than_1000:
        return 1
    if n > 1000:
        for p in primes_less_than_1000:
            if (n%p==0):
                factor = 1
                return 0
        if (factor==0):
            return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Now that we have a prime-determining function, we can test any range below 1 million:

```
def primes_in_range(lower,upper):
    primes = []
    for n in range(lower,upper):
        if is_prime(n)==1:
            primes.append(n)
    return primes
```

For example:

```
print(primes_in_range(1000,1100))
>>> [1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097]
```

If you want primes more than 1 million, trial divison will take up more memory, so you should look at https://primes.utm.edu/ for other prime or probable prime algorithms.